# NSTextFiled lose control in NSTableRowView. Why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstablerowview

[image]

I use NSOutlineview to group a view(the view align left side of NSOutlineView), So I subclass the NSTableRowView as a view. then putting NSTextField for something control. But NSTextField can't work inside NSTableRowView.

Anyone can give me advice.
Thank a lot.

Comment: once you select the row, have you try pressing Tab?

Comment: Hi Anoop Vaidya,
You are collect, I need to set the NSTableRowView can be selected, But I have to click twice at NSTextField that NSTextField is selected. How to solve the double click problem?
thanks

Comment: I using [outlineViw setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone]; to solve this problem. thanks all.